# Why do I get Access Denied when accessing a remote path as local administrator?

Tags: windows, authentication, privileges, administrator

I have a Windows-xp-sp3 virtual machine, with configured NAT, disabled firewall, and ping-able ip address.

I'm trying to access `\\<vm-name>\c$` from my computer.

I entered the `<vm-name>\Administrator` user in the prompted authentication window, yet I get Access is Denied.
When I configure "Everyone" to be an administrator on my VM, I can access the path.

Why do I get "Access is Denied" as a vm-local administrator user?

**Edit**: Solved the problem thanks to this blog:
http://chall32.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/how-to-enable-access-windows-7.html

You can run this line on your remote machine:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: Does the Administrator account have a password?

Comment: I tried both with and without a password, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Questioner provided the answer themselves.  Running a simple Registry tweak on the remote machine (i.e., the host of the file being accessed) does the job --

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Answer based on [a blog post](http://chall32.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/how-to-enable-access-windows-7.html), and backed up by [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016).